# run docker under supervisor, can not enable tty error

Tags: docker, supervisord, tty

I am trying to run an start container under supervisor, which at the moment looks like this

```
[program:api]
directory=/api/
command=/usr/bin/docker run -it --name api --env-file ./api/api.env --rm  -p 8080:8080 588n8b6d7cbd
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisor-docker-api-out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisor-docker-api-err.log
priority=1
```

when I do this, i get the process fails to run and I get the error below

```
cannot enable tty mode on non tty input
```

If I remove the -it option then the process runs fine, however, when I tell supervisor to stop, the actual docker container is still running.

I can not modify the image in any way, so can not get the method here [Shutting down Docker containers via supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197724/shutting-down-docker-containers-via-supervisor) to help me out.

I am using docker 1.11.2 on ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you need supervisor to create a daemon of the docker process (which already has a daemon)?

Comment: The docker container has crashed a couple of times. The supervisor is so that if it crashes, it will automatically restart the process. I understand that finding the reason of the container is crashing should be the main focus, but that is not what I have been asked to do.

Comment: There is a restart flag that you can give to the docker command. Otherwise, as you've discovered from the linked post is that some variant of kill signals don't get passed into the container from supervisor.  See here for more info.  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart